# jquery alternative to td.cellIndex

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-browser

I've got some javascript code referencing

```
var cell = event.target
if (cell.cellIndex === 3) {
    ...
}
```

Is the cellIndex property safe to use?

What would be a good cross-browser alternative?

jQuery is allowed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`cellIndex` is  supported by all major browsers<sup>[[src]](http://help.dottoro.com/ljputote.php)</sup> and is defined in DOM level 2<sup>[[src]](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-80748363)</sup>.  Stick with that.  In jQuery, you can use:

```
$('#myTD')[0].cellIndex;
```

jQuery's [`index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index) <strike>might also be optimized to make use of `cellIndex` where available,</strike> would also work, though it would be less efficient because it works by getting an array of the parent node's children and finding the index of the current element in that array.

Comment: I like your [src] things. Handy way to deal with SO not underlining links.

Comment: @TJC: I felt like trying something different :-)

Comment: pity the only reference to the `cellIndex` property online are W3Schools & MSDN, so it didn't trust it.

Comment: @Raynos: maybe a glass of milk and a cookie will make you feel better? Oh, and [this too](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_html.html#tables).

Comment: a link to quirksmode is good enough. Trust that more then totoro.